# Comparison of object property to string fails in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

**Conclusion: It was a typo.**

I'm trying something something which seems simple, but I think I'm missing out on something fundamental to Vue. I have an id, and an object with once child property that contains an object with that id. When I loop through the object properties to compare the id, it is false. When I log the values that were compared in the else statement after the comparison, they appear to be identical in the console log.

Whatever I try it, I keep ending up on the "bad package" line.
The console shows me that the object property is there and that the id of the object at that property is correct. It looks like:

`bad package  c5186ae5-1558-490b-a9d2-5fc19c0a736d  !==  c5186ae5-1588-490b-a9d2-5fc19c0a736d`

I suspect it is something to do with observables in Vue, even though the log doesn't show anything as an observable.

What's the right way to do what I'm trying to do?

```js
// newVal = '29e51254-a88a-4309-92bc-ad1d0cda1427'
collectionIdForVerification (newVal) {
         const parcelId = this.$store.state.parcels.collectionIdForVerification
         // this print the object, it looks good
         console.log('Parcels are ', this.requestedParcelsForCollection)
         console.log('local parcels are ', this.local.parcels)
         const loParcOb = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.local.parcels))
         console.log('local parcels are ', loParcOb)
         console.log('does the parcel for ', newVal, ' exist? ', this.local.parcels[newVal])
         if (newVal) {
           const packages = loParcOb
           console.log('lets check ', packages, ' for ', parcelId)
           const rightPackage = loParcOb[parcelId]
           console.log('right package is ', rightPackage)
           for (let x in loParcOb) {
             let ob = loParcOb[x]
             console.log('object: ', ob)
             if (ob.id.toString() === parcelId) {
               console.log('good pagage ', ob)
             } else {
               // this shows me that the two compared things are equal
               console.log('bad package ', ob.id.toString(), ' !== ', parcelId)
             }
           }
         }
       }
```

Object:

```js
// object
{
displayImage: "https://static.xxxx.co/couriers/dhl/dhl_detail.png"
expiration: 1573486971237
id: "29e51254-a88a-4309-92bc-ad1d0cda1427"
name: "MacBook from YYYY"
passcode: ""
recipient: {xxxId: "0cbf8068-a286-49c5-bdf7-7509ac953b5f", yyyId: "b925b763-992e-4ad3-98b1-ba8fba2ef37e"}
sender: {xxxId: "9cad32d0-6724-414b-a686-a8e133db2225", yyyId: "997eeab8-a698-4027-93d3-43ca5d6ee121"}
slotHeight: 2
startingSlot: 37
status: "IN_STATION"
trackingNumber: "A123456002"
}
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be a Vue problem. The logging has `parcelId` but the `if` check has `newVal`. Are you sure `newVal` is a string?

Comment: I've changed to use parcelId, they're the same value but form different places. no dice. I suspect it's not a string but a reactive property. I just don't know how I should compare a reactive property.

Comment: Try wrapping the logged value in `JSON.stringify`. e.g. `console.log(JSON.stringify(parcelId))`. That'll make it easier to spot common problems like trailing white-space.

Comment: I tried that as well as escape() and trim() character length is identical when they get logged, but that's the result of the getter I think, not sure

Comment: Have you not seen my answer? The ids are different.

Comment: I did eventually, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ids are different.

One contains `1558`. The other has `1588`.

Comment: that's the one, how did I convince myself the issue had to be complicated. I had manually copied the UUID and made a typo.